# Why is there main and title?

Tags: r, plot, program-entry-point, title

There are two different options (`main` within the plot and `title` afterwards, which calls `main` again) to add an header to the plot. I want to know what is the difference between these two. Which one shall I use?

The code below gives a minimal example and produces the graphs.

```
library(mvtnorm)
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
x = rmvnorm(10,c(2,2),matrix(c(2,0,0,2),2))
plot(x, main='title')
plot(x)
title(main='title')
```

[image: <code>Title</code> and <code>main</code> used for two graphs.]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you read the help files? `?title`

Comment: `plot` calls `title` which makes a title (it's not that `title` calls `main` - that's just impossible). the `main` argument is for convenience  - you can make a simple plot with a title in just one line. in the same way you can make points, lines, axes, axis labels either from within `plot` or using separate fns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are identical except that `title` allows you to add a title after making the plot, as opposed to defining it atomically. Use whichever is most convenient.  If you have a lot of arguments specified within `plot`, you might like to specify the title on a separate line to make your code more readable, for example.

To see that they are equivalent, look at the definition of `plot.default()` in your console. The very last line is an indirect call to `title()` where `main` and `sub` are passed through:

```
> plot.default
function (x, y = NULL, type = "p", xlim = NULL, ylim = NULL, 
    log = "", main = NULL, sub = NULL, xlab = NULL, ylab = NULL, 
    ann = par("ann"), axes = TRUE, frame.plot = axes, panel.first = NULL, 
    panel.last = NULL, asp = NA, ...) 
{

    # [code left out for clarity]

    localTitle <- function(..., col, bg, pch, cex, lty, lwd) title(...)

    # [code left out for clarity]

    if (ann) 
        localTitle(main = main, sub = sub, xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab, 
            ...)
    invisible()
}
```